# Prove the inequality using Chebyshev's Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, symmetric-polynomials, holder-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

If $a,b,c \in(0,\infty)$, then prove that: $$9(a^3+b^3+c^3)\ge(a+b+c)^3$$

I was trying to prove this inequality using Chebyshev's Inequality and assuming $a\ge b \ge c$ but to no avail.

Can please someone help me in proving it using Chebyshev's Inequality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $(a,b,c)$ and $(a^2,b^2,c^2)$ they are the same ordered, by Chebyshov twice we ontain:
$$9(a^3+b^3+c^3)=3\cdot3(a^3+b^3+c^3)\geq3(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq(a+b+c)^3.$$

Also, by Holder
$$(1+1+1)^2(a^3+b^3+c^3)\geq\left(\sqrt[3]{1^2a^3}+\sqrt[3]{1^2b^3}+\sqrt[3]{1^2c^3}\right)^3=(a+b+c)^3.$$

Comment: How $3(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq(a+b+c)^3$?

Comment: Because by Chebyshov $3(a^2+b^2+c^2)=3(a\cdot a+b\cdot b+c\cdot c)\geq(a+b+c)(a+b+c)=(a+b+c)^2.$

Comment: Ohh..Clear.. Thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: And here I was looking for a fancy probability distribution to solve it... ;p

Answer (score 4):

Recall that by the [generalized mean inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean)

$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}}\ge \frac{a+b+c}{3}$$

and the result directly follows.

Comment: Can't this be done by using Chebyshev's Inequality?

Comment: It doesn’t seem convenient in that case. Are you forced to use that?

Comment: Yes..............

Comment: I see now that Michael has solved in that way!

Comment: Yes... By the way, thanks to you too. Your method was great too.

Comment: You are welcome! Bye